How long is a cycle in the Alien universe?
In the movie, Alien Romulus, there are a couple of occasions characters mentioning cycle or cycles as a measurement of time.
Rain goes up to an admin and claims she has completed her promised hours working as a miner; a piece of info she provides is her parents have died three cycles ago.
I am wondering how a cycle is measured and how many years make up a cycle?

Most likely, cycle = 1 Earth Year but since most planetary years are different from Earth's they use "cycle" instead of "year" to avoid confusion.

Likewise, how long is an "hour"...I assume they are referring to 60 Earth minutes and not one planetary hour, however long that might be.

They may use cycle to mean a local year - and year to mean a standard earth year.

Units of measure are often left ambiguous in fiction to avoid inconsistencies arising.

I aboslutely took it to mean a local year - as in whatever the local planetary and orbital mechanics deem, because presumably, they are so far there is less in common with an Earth year. Also note, the readout for the colony says: Hours of sunlight: 0, so they had to make up a local clock, and cycles leaves it less demoralising when its all just night.

Not a definitive answer but one that has a toe-hold, I think:
The establishing shot of the colony states:

Hours of daylight per year: 0

So, you know already that is pretty miserable - no chance of ever seeing day light.
Traditionally, a year as we know it is us going around the sun for a particular period of time.
The same must be said for this planet, but with no days and all nights, that is going to be depressing for an already clearly demoralized colony (no mention of seasons though, presumably only one: grim), so instead of making a glaring connection to a home and a sun that they will never see, replace 'year' with 'cycle' - technically meaning same thing, but without  the connotations of (life on Earth, sun, warmth, seasons, etc) that that brings.


Hours of Daylight = 0. "Welcome to Planet England"

A lot of time units in our own world are based on cyclical events:

A year is the time it takes the Earth to fully revolve around the Sun. Even in historic times when people did not understand that the Earth revolves around the Sun, they could still observe that the Sun would sometimes be higher and sometimes be lower above the horizon, or that the days would get longer and shorter, and you could use these cycles to define a year.
A day is the time it takes the Earth to fully revolve around itself. Again, even without understanding that the Earth is a sphere (more specifically, an oblate spheroid) and that it rotates, there are still cyclical events happening that you can observe, most obviously, day and night.
A month is (very roughly) the time it takes for the Moon to go from a New Moon to a Full Moon and back.

All of these things also happen on other planets that rotate, revolve around the Sun, and have moons. But, of course, they take different amounts of time compared to other planets.
For example, a year on Mars is, same as on Earth, the time it takes Mars to complete a full revolution around the Sun. But, it takes Mars about 1.88 times as long to revolve around the Sun as it takes the Earth, so a Mars Year is 1.88 times longer than an Earth Year. Interestingly, Mars rotates almost as fast as the Earth, so a Mars Day is only very slightly longer than an Earth Day.
Venus rotates around its own axis 243 times slower than Earth, meaning that one Venus Day is as long as 243 Earth Days! Interestingly, Venus revolves around the Sun 1.6 times as fast as the Earth, and thus a Venus Day is actually longer than a Venus Year!
So, as you can see, cyclical naturally occurring events have always been used to define time. But, in an interplanetary and even interstellar civilization, it makes a very big difference, which star, planet, and moon you use as your reference. The engineers which operate NASA's Mars rovers, for example, live on Mars time, which means their workday shifts by 40 minutes each day compared to Earth day. If today, the Sun rises over Perseverance at 9am, giving them a normal Earth workday, in 3 weeks, the Sun will rise over Perseverance at 9pm, forcing them to sleep during the Earth Day and work through the Earth Night.
If we keep using the names "day" and "year", things might get confusing. So, on Earth, we typically reserve the (unqualified) terms to refer to Earth and use either a qualified term like "Martian Day" or "Jovian Year", or we use another term like "Sol". The term "Sol" is used by NASA mission engineers, for example, to mean "one rotation of whatever planet we are currently operating on". So, for the Mars mission teams, a "Sol" would be a Martian Day, for one of the future Venus missions, it would be a Venutian Day.
It has been a well-used trope in science-fiction at this point to use a term like "cycle" to mean either "day" or "year", similar to how we use new terms here on Earth.
I don't think it is particularly well-defined how long a "cycle" is in this context compared to Earth times such as days or years. Out-of-universe, it sounds like it is just sci-fi techno babble for "we acknowledge that keeping time on other planets is weird, but the writers don't want to get into the specifics because it is not really relevant to the plot".
So, in other words, a "cycle" is just some cyclical event that is used to define time, presumably, one full orbit of planet Jackson around its star.

Unfortunately while well written, this does not provide an answer to the question itself.  I can tell from the question that the OP knew that a cycle was a term to define time and perhaps why it was being used and not year but they are asking how much time.  If the question was 'why do they use the term cycle ...' then this would be a great answer.
